# monerov windows wallet gui.exe showing up as Trojan

Tags: security, monero-forks

Why is moneorv windows wallet gui.exe being quarantined as Trojan.BitCoinMiner by malwarebytes ?

[image: gui.exe as trojan ?]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because monerov

Answer (score 2):

Because you can mine MoneroV with it and that is considered a malware by antivirus software. Monero has the same problem (MoneroV wallet is a clone of the Monero wallet).

Other mining software have the same issue. For example XMRig shows up also as a malware.

Comment: Monero wallet installation didn't get flagged as trojan by malwarebytes

Comment: That depends on the virus scanner